# Ubuntu 14.04 not loading GUI - problems with startx

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gui

Yesterday I tried to update Google-Chrome and to install Chromium, I don't know if it is related, but after that I restarted my computer and now it does not load the graphic interface. I can log in through ctrl + alt + f4, however if I try to run startx it gives me a black screen.

Does anybody have any idea of what to do?

**-- purging Chrome makes no effect. Problem is with startx. However, once again, as much as I have tried following other topics, no results so far.**

Comment: Any errors (lines with (EE)" in /var/log/Xorg.0.log?

Comment: I had this problem yesterday after installing Nvidia driver; wasn't able to repair. @ubfan1

Answer (score 0):

Sounds totally weird. 
I would switch to runlevel 2 and purge chromium...reboot.
If the problem still occurs, again runlevel 2 and purge google-chrome.

Tell me/us what happened.